# What does inclusion-minimal maximizer mean?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, discrete-optimization

In set theory, combinatorial optimization etc, I came across the term called inclusion-minimal maximizer. What is it's definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In combinatorial optimization, it is common for solutions to be represented by sets of objects. There may be multiple optimal solutions to a combinatorial optimization problem. Moreover, since these optimal solutions are represented by sets, some optimal solutions may be strictly contained within others. An **inclusion-wise minimal maximizer** is a set that maximizes your objective function, while simultaneously not being a proper subset of any other maximizer.

For example, consider the following:

*Example: Consider the set X = {-2, -1, 1,2}. Find a subset of A$\subseteq$ X such that

- A has at most 2 elements, and
- the product of the elements in A is maximized.

For example, A = {-2,1} will give a product of -2 while A = {-1} will give a product of -1.*

*Answer: {-2,-1}, {1,2}, and {2} are all maximizers for this problem. However, only {-2,-1} and {2} are inclusion-wise minimal maximizers.*

Comment: Did you mean to say absolute value of the product in this example?

Comment: For the example, I don't believe an absolute value is needed.

Comment: ok yeah BTW WHY is {-2,-1,2} not a minimal maximizer? It gives 4!

Comment: Oh, you are exactly right. That is my fault. I will edit the answer.

Comment: I adjusted the example slightly so that there would still be a minimal maximizer and a non-minimal maximizer.

Comment: Can you explain why {-2,-1,2} is not a minimal maximizer? I really need an explanation for this, to get my understanding right.

Comment: I tried to fix the example because of your previous edit. I added the stipulation that a valid set can have at most 2 elements. Since {-2,-1,2} has 3 elements, it is not valid.

Comment: Why do you say {-2,-1}, {2} are minimal maximizers and why not {-2, -1} , {1,2} ? These are not proper subsets of each other either!!! Why did you choose those two instead of these two? Aren't there two solutions sets for mininal maximizers?

Comment: So here are the possible maximizers (note that they must satisfy that there are at most two elements):

{-2, -1}, {2}, and {1,2}

Now, as a subset  {-2,-1} does not contain either {2} or {1,2}. Therefore {-2,-1} is the minimal.

Now, as a subset  {2} does not contain either {-2,-1} or {1,2}. Therefore {2} is the minimal.

Finally, as a subset  {1,2} does contain {2}, which is also a maximizer. Therefore {1,2} contains a subset (i.e. something smaller) that is also a maximizer. Hence {1,2} is not minimal (because there is a smaller maximizer contained inside of it)

Comment: That's perfectly explained..Thanks!

Comment: @JSP: the answer says “An inclusion-wise minimal maximizer is a set that maximizes your objective function, while simultaneously not being a proper subset of any other maximizer.”, but it also says that {2} is inclusion-minimal, and {2} is a proper subset of {1, 2}. Should the definition say “not a proper *superset*”? i.e., it is inclusion-minimal because no other maximizer is included in it?